# How to reuse function specialization code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void fun(const T & val)
{
   cout << " T " << endl;
}

template<>
void fun<int>(const int & val)
{
   cout << " specialization same code " << val << endl;
}

template<>
void fun<double>(const double& val)
{
   cout << " specialization same code " << val << endl;
}


int main()
{
    fun( 1 );
    fun( 1.0 );
    fun( 'c' );
    return 0;
}
```

Question> Is there a way that I can reuse the function specialization code?
For example, assume both 'int and 'double' specialization has the exactly same implementation code. Is there a method I can prevent the code duplication?

http://codepad.org/awGYWiWv

Thank you

Comment: Create a function and call them from both specializations.

Comment: You could call one specialization from the other

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @0x499602D2 in the comments, create another function and make sure it gets called only for `int` or `double`.

```
template<typename T>
void bar(const T & val)
{
   // Make sure this gets called only for int or double.
   static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, double>::value);

   // Do useful stuff with val.
}

template<>
void fun<int>(const int & val)
{
   bar(val);
}

template<>
void fun<double>(const double& val)
{
   bar(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To reuse the same code for multiple types of the same kind, you could use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) (or [`boost::enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) if you are not using C++11) with [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) (a nice example is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Example)).

e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type 
fun(const T& val) 
{
    cout << " floating point specialisation " << val << endl;
}
```

(function specialisations of this kind work only in C++11, but you can use a struct or class for the same purpose in older C++ versions)

Answer (score 0):

something like this should give you the level of re-use you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

// will only compile if T is an arithmetic type
template<typename T, 
         typename std::enable_if<
           std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void fun(T val)
{
    cout << "the square is " << val * val << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    double y = 10;

    fun(x);
    fun(y);

   return 0;
}
```